# Object reference not set to instance of an object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, instance

Why am I getting the error "Object reference not set to instance of an object" with my code?

```
Public Class Form2
  Dim i As Integer = 0

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

  Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPatient.Click

        Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text
        i = i + 1
  End Sub
End Class
```

Names() is a global variable

Thanks

**Updated:**

```
Module Module1
    Public Names() As String
    Public Heights() As Integer
    Public Weights() As Integer
End Module


Public Class Form2

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPatient.Click


        ReDim Preserve Names(0 To i)
        Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text

        ReDim Preserve Heights(0 To i)
        Heights(i) = txtPatientHeight.Text

        ReDim Preserve Weights(0 To i)
        Weights(i) = txtPatientWeight.Text

        i = i + 1

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which line you are getting error? What is Names? Is it array? Where is code for Names?

Comment: What is Names? Is it array?

Comment: The error is pointing to: Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text, Names is an array and it is declared as a global variable across all forms in the module

Comment: I am sure you are not able to access this variable and hence getting error? can you show how Names is declared

Comment: can you put this code in your question?

Comment: how are you accessing Module class in your form?

Comment: I am just using the Module to define the arrays, what do I need to do to access the module class in the form?

Comment: you have to do dim modClass = new Module1()
then use modClass.Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text

Comment: i = i + 1?  You are trying to create a loop on a textbox?  that makes no sense to me.  I think you just want to add the item from the textbox to the array.  The way you are doing this, i would declare names as an array list `shared names as arraylist` then in your event handler `names.add(txtpatientname.txt.tostring)`

Comment: ok but now I get the error Module 'Module1' cannot be used as type

Comment: I have the i = i + 1 so that when the user adds a name and clicks the button the i increases so that the next name that is entered is put into the next element

Comment: I have moved the i declaration to inside the event handler. and what does the error "Module 'Module1' cannot be used as type" mean?

Comment: it is just a Module I created so that I could declare the arrays globally so that they will be defined across all the forms, as I still have to list the arrays in a different form

Comment: can you try to do dim modClass = new Module1

Comment: you need to declare module as Public Module Module1

Comment: how do I declare the module as Public? Do I just typed "modClass = Public Module Module1"?

Comment: Definately a case where you need `List(Of String)` instead of `String()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using a module, you should redim preserve your array.

```
Public Module Module1
    Public i As Integer = 0
    Public Names() As String
    Public Heights() As Integer
    Public Weights() As Integer
End Module

Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnterPatient_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        ReDim Preserve Names(0 To i)
        Names(i) = txtpatientName.Text

        ReDim Preserve Heights(0 To i)
        Heights(i) = txtpatientheight.Text

        ReDim Preserve Weights(0 To i)
        Weights(i) = txtpatientweight.Text

        i = i + 1

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        For Each j In Names
            MsgBox(j.ToString)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thankyou the code for button 2 worked for me, however 'i' will only increment once on the first click and after entering another name, it does not increment

Comment: well I is dimensioned in form1.  add I into your module.  `  Public i As Integer = 0`

Comment: honestly from the same form (form1) it should have worked the same but to make it compatible across forms you would need to anyway.

Comment: I added it into my module however it still does not increase after it reaches 1

Comment: add  MsgBox(i.ToString) to button2 after you increment I.  it should msg an increment.  it does in my source.

Comment: No worries I found out why, 'Dim i As Integer = 0' was within the button event handler so it kept resetting to zero, thanks for the help

Comment: ;-)  glad its resolved. obj ref's are ambiguous and a pain to resolve.  Good luck!

Comment: Also one thing, what does the ReDim Preserve code do? Just want to know how it managed to fix the error.

Comment: in an update i added my new code but for some reason the i will not increment at all, any ideas?

Comment: Is I declared in more than one form as a shared or public variable?  Im thinking its updating the wrong "i"

Comment: I just removed the declaration from the module so now it is only in the one form and it is still not incrementing

Comment: I wish you had more rep so you could chat...  can you paste the full code in an update?

Comment: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid. is the error I get when I enter nothing in the height or weight text boxes

Comment: That is probably unrelated to the code at hand in the answer.  You have a function somewhere else that is doing something with the value from the height field.  However, you could wrap the textboxes with any condition you want to prevent bad data from being entered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make module as public. So i suggest below

```
Public Module Module1
   Public Names() As String
   Public Heights() As Integer
   Public Weights() As Integer
End Module
```

Then access it in form like

```
Dim mod1 = Module1
mod1.Names(i) = txtPatientName.Text
```

Comment: I am still receiving the error "'Module1' is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

Comment: This was the correct course of action, but the array needed to be "redim preserve" on the event when a record is added.